# Finding the two unknown constants of the logistic function $f(x) = \frac{158}{1+e^{s(x-c)}}+22$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, constants, logistic-regression

I'm trying to find the two unknown constants of the following function:

$$f(x) = \frac{158}{1+e^{s(x-c)}}+22$$
Where s and c are constants, and 22 (or $y_{min}$) and 180 (or $y_{max}$) are the horizontal asymptotes. c is the integration constant.

This was integrated from the following ODE (Ricatti equation):

$$\frac{s}{158}\frac{dy}{dx}=a(y-22)(180-y) , f(0) = y_0 > 22 $$

I can assume that f(0) lies near the horizontal asymptote. Additionally, I have the following equations:

$$f(0) = y_0 = \frac{158}{1+e^{sc}}+22$$
Hence
$$c = \frac{1}{s} log \frac{180 - y_0 }{y_0 - 22}$$

How do I find both constants mathematically? I realize that I need two equations, but am unsure of how I can find them.
From plugging in this into Desmos, I have found that c is the inflection point of the graph, while s is responsible for the shape of the curve: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hwg4vsewro

The broader context of this question is that I'm finding a logistic function to fit a set of data (x is time, y is angle).

For context of the equations, I followed this source: http://sciendo.com/article/10.2478/fman-2020-0007

This is my raw data. Left column is x value(seconds); right is y value(angle).

**x   y**

0   22

60  23

120 24

180 27

240 32

300 32

360 36

420 36

480 39

540 41

600 42

660 45

720 46

750 51

780 54

810 57

840 63

870 79

900 103

930 124

960 155

990 177

1020    180

1080    180

1140    180

1200    180

I did not find an explanation of exactly how they find s and c, although the source has some quite complex equations involving higher order derivatives.

(One that I think might be useful involves the x-value $x_0$, where the function's second derivative takes its maximum value.

$$f(x_0) = \frac{y_{max}-y_{min}}{1+e^{s(x_0-c)}}+y_{min}$$
$$f(x_0) = y_{min} + 0.211(y_{max}-y_{min}) = 22 + 0.211(180-22) =55.338$$
No explanation why $\frac{1}{1+e^{s(x_0-c)}}=22$. From which it is somehow calculated:
$$x_0 = c - \frac{1.319}{s}$$)

Comment: You wrote : I'm finding a logistic function to fit a set of data (x is time, y is angle). Thus what you did is not the right way. You cannot analytically find EXACT values for $s$ and $c$ from a set of $n$ experimental points $(x,y)$. The problem is to compute approximative values of $s$ and $c$ so that the function fits as well as possible the data according to some criteria of fitting. This is a non-linear "regression" problem . Edit in your question a representative example of data so that one can show you how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = \frac{158}{1+e^{s(x-c)}}+22$$
The given data is :
$$(x_1,f_1),(x_2,f_2),..., (x_k,f_k),..., (x_n,f_n)$$
Let :
$$Y(x)=\ln\left(\frac{158}{f(x)-22}-1 \right)$$
So, for each $f_k$ compute :
$$Y_k=\ln\left(\frac{158}{f_k-22}-1 \right)$$
The original equation becomes :
$$Y=s\:x-s\:c$$
You can compute approximate values of $(s)$ and $(-s\:c)$ thanks to linear regression (Least Mean Squares).

NOTE: Some difficulties may arrise due to eventually negative argument of the logarithm. That is why a representative example of data would be useful to check if the difficulties appear in your case and eventually suggest what to do.

NOTE: If a particular criteria of fitting is specified, you need a non-linear regression method. Then use a specialized software involving itterative calculus and guessed initial values of the parameters. The approximate values found above can be used as initial values.

UPDATED ANSWER with the given data.

Drawing $Y(x)=\ln\left(\frac{158}{y(x)-22}-1 \right)$ shows this shape of curve :

[image]

The curve is far to be linear. This proves that the chosen model $(1)$ is not convenient to obtain a good fitting whatever the method of calculus of the parameters.

$$y=a+\frac{b}{1+e^{s(x-c)}} \tag {model 1}$$

As a consequence the above proposed method is of no interest in the present case.

We have to look for another model.

For example one can try with the sum of two logistic functions :

$$y=A+\frac{b_1}{1+e^{s_1(x-c_1)}}+\frac{b_2}{1+e^{s_2(x-c_2)}} \tag {model 2}$$

The result is much better. Below, the comparison between the two models.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer - it certainly helped me look in the right direction, but I still don't fully understand: first, what is a 'representative sample' of data and why is mine not? I follow the Y(x) reasoning, although I got $Y = sx - sc$. However, I don't fully understand the computation of s and sc values with least mean squares regression, at least plugging $Y=sx+sc$ into Desmos gave very inaccurate values for s and c: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gfppy5alzg .

Is just plugging into Desmos an incorrect way to find s and c and if so, how do I do LMS for $Y=sx+sc$ ?

Comment: It should be very easy to explain with a numerical example. There is no "representative example" joint to your question because there is no NUMERICAL set of $n$ couples $(x,f(x))$. May be with a number of couples $n$ smaller than in your real data, but representing correctly an example of your data.

Comment: I have tried the linear regression (least square regression for the data and then matching $y = ax + b$ to $y = sx - sc$), and I get values for s and c which are far from a good approximation for the logistic curve (see previous comment's Desmos link). I feel like I did something wrong, maybe the two Ys can't be equated? Also since I only have real-world data, I can't possibly get a representative sample, right? Apologies about not grasping anything, I am completely new to computing regressions.

Comment: I guess what is the trouble. But I need your NUMERICAL data to check and give the solution. Once again and for the last time, can you edit IN YOUR QUESTION the data that you used for your calculus If this is the data given in desmos, I cannot import it. I don't like copy the numbers one after the other.

Comment: I've added in the numerical data now. Sorry, misinterpreted the prior comments.

Comment: OK. I updated my answer.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the help, this is seriously lifesaving! What software can I use to fit the new model? Desmos doesn't seem able to be able to create this line of best fit with so many parameters. (it would also help me to know what kind of regression is applied so I can explain how the parameters are estimated).

And how would one explain why using the sum of two logistic functions works better?

Comment: Generally increasing the number of adjustable parameters improves the fit. There is no theoretical clue for the choice of two logistic functions. Without context one cannot guess what will be the most convenient. Simply I try it. For the non-linear regression I used an home-made software. I have no sufficient experience with commercial softwares of this kind to give advices. The large number of adjustable parameters is certainly a major difficulty. May be fully different models might be convenient in practice.  For example piecewise functions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Would it be possible to share your home-made software so I can get the same results? (Not at all a problem if not, I think I can find something myself but it would take time to get administrator permissions on my PC.) 

I was also wondering about the Y(x) you drew, shouldn't everything cancel out to become a linear function $Y = sx - sc$?

Comment: Sorry my software is not portable. It requires the progiciel DELPHI to be bought from Borland and to be familiar with implementation and Delphi programmation. The code must be addapted in each case of application. About your second question : The method first proposed to linearise with $Y(x)=sx-sc$ is valid only for one logistic function not for two. Forgot the first part of my answer given before I get the data. If the data was available at this time I would not have proposed this method.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, you quite literally saved my whole paper. I don't know why you're saving people's lives without asking for anything in return, but am eternally grateful!